# How to set long password for MySQL user?

Tags: macos, mysql

I want to set user password of length more than 32 characters. But got an error `password is too long`. Is there any settings that I can change and use long password? I'm using MAMP PRO 4.4.1, MySQL 5.6.38 on mac os High Sierra